# How to add a custom PHP page in Magento ?

Tags: php, template, custom

### Details

- I already have the `.phtml` file
- The actual path = `/var/www/html/store/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/distributors.phtml`

After doing some research I found that I will have to add this

`{{block type="core/template" template="/var/www/html/store/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/distributors.phtml"}}`

Where **exactly** are we suppose to add this ?

I logged in to Mogento Admin. 
Go to CMS > Pages > Add New Page, and then I don't know what else to do ?

Can someone help shed the light on this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to add this .phtml script inside the middle of a CMS page, you can paste that text right into the content area of the CMS page's WYSIWYG editor. Magento will know to parse the text out, detect the block, and render out your view script.

Note: your "template" attribute includes too much, you only need to specify the path afer the "template" directory. A name to your block is also required, otherwise it will not be rendered. So, it should be more like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="my_distributors_block" template="page/distributors.phtml"}}
```

I'm going to assume this .phtml file, despite being located in the "page" directory, is just a small block which you'd like to render within a page. (NOT an entirely new page layout). If this "discributors.phtml" script is indeed a page layout, then this answer is not what you're looking for.

Lastly, you really should be putting this .phtml file within your own theme directory, not base. Unless this view script belongs to an extension which you plan to re-use for multiple projects. I'd suggest reading up on how to configure Magento to use your own theme, and the fallback logic Magento uses to find view scripts.

Comment: I pasted this `{{block type="core/template" name="my_distributors_block" template="page/distributors.phtml"}}` in. Save > Preview. I didn't see any changes. :(

Comment: Have you tried turning logging on under System  -> Configuration -> Developer -> Log Settings. Afterwards, load up your page on the front end, then check to see if there is any errors logged in system.log or exception.log?

Comment: No I have now, but I will do it now.

Comment: My guess is your path to your template file may be slightly off. Just to confirm, you're looking to add a small "block" **within** your cms page's main content area right? Not define an entirely new layout for the page.

Comment: I am looking to add a small block. How do I check to see if I have the correct path ? I am sure the file(distributors.phtml) is there because I moved it into my server using WinSCP. Plus, I saw the file there as well when I refresh

Comment: After loading the page on the front end, is there any messages showing up in `var/log/system.log` or `var/log/exception.log` ?